# Ĉu oni pagas ion aŭ por io?

Tags: verbs

Mi provis legi PIV, kaj ŝajnas ke la verbo "pagi" povas preni multajn objektojn; ricevanto, mono, ŝuldo. Sed kio pri tion kion oni ricevas reen? Tion kion oni aĉetas? Ĉu oni pagas "ĝin" aŭ "por ĝi"?

Comment: Memorigas min pri la tikla verbo ‘provizi’.

Answer (score 3):

Efektive en PIV estas multaj ekzemploj.

- mi pagis por la presado ĉirkaŭ 420 rublojn<sup>Z</sup>
- pagi la manĝojn, la loĝejon<sup>B</sup>

Comment: Ĉu ne la ekzemplo B simple montras anstataŭigon de prepozicio per akuzativo, simile al ”Mi vojaĝas Moskvon” por ”Mi vojaĝas al Moskvo”? Eble la fonto estis poezieca teksto kies aŭtoro tiel ”mallongigis” pro iu arta celo?

Comment: Miaopnie, ne. Legu mem en PIV. Cetere, ne eblas libere anstatauxigi prepozicion per -n.

Comment: Mi legis, kaj vi ŝajne pravas… Kiom da ebloj por la objekto de ”pagi”! Esperanto estas malfacila lingvo sufiĉe komplika! ’:-)

Comment: (Ho mi mistajpis, mi celis skribi ”facila lingvo sufiĉe komplika”!)